# Cannot Set CSS Property of Parent "<tr>" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `table` like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody style="border: 4px solid red;">
        <tr>
            <td class="HeaderOfTable" style="width:5%; padding:5px;">#</td>
            <td class="HeaderOfTable" style="width:70%; padding:5px;">Title</td>
            <td class="HeaderOfTable" style="width:10%; padding:5px;">Number of Items</td>
            <td class="HeaderOfTable" style="width:15%; padding:5px;">Operations</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Gone With the Wind</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="btnShowSearchResults" value="Show Item Details">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And `jQuery` code like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btnShowSearchResults', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').css('border', '1px solid red');
});
```

The problem is obvious: The parent `'tr'`s border won't change! Please note that:

- This works perfectly for other elements:

`$(this).parent().css('border', '1px solid red');` Works!
`$(this).parents('tr').parent().css('border', '1px solid red');` Works!
`$(this).parent().prev().css('border', '1px solid red');` Works!

- After executing, the parent tr's style becomes `<tr style="display:table-row; border: 1px solid red;">` but still no change in the browser!
- Finally, I think this doesn't work for `'tr'`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to apply `border` to `tr` elements, you need

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QhVpK/2/)

Comment: It seems logical but why doesn't it work for me? (even though "tr"s have now the "style=border-collapse: collapse;" but there's no border yet...

Comment: It works!!! Thanks :) I was setting border-collapse on tr but following your fiddle I set it on table and I now works! cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You found the solution by yourself : You can't use `border` on `tr` tags. This has nothing to do with jQuery or parent().

Applying it on every `td` of the row instead could be a way to do. Depends on your needs.

Comment: really? thanks... I thought these CSS styles were applicable to every element on DOM :(
So how am I supposed to border a tr for user notification? (td's would be bordered separately which is ugly)
P.S.: When you can't trust CSS, who could you trust anymore? :D